# An anonymous function can have more than one output arguments?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

From [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f4-2525.html)

> An anonymous function consists of a single MATLAB expression and any number of input and
>   output arguments.

I wonder how an anonymous function can have more than one output arguments? Thanks and regards!

Comment: Check out this [post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/01/31/multiple-outputs/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the expression which your anonymous function is executing can return more than one value, then so can your anonymous function.
For example, using the [max](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) function which can return both the max value of an array and its index:

```
arr = [1 2 4 3];
anon = @(y) max(y);
[maxVal, ind] = anon(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily return multiple values from an anonymous function using `deal`:

```matlab
meanAndStd = @(x)deal(mean(x), std(x));
[meanValue, stdValue] = meanAndStd(randn(1000));
```